# Android imageView with checkeredBackground and different size images ontop

Tags: android, background, imageview

**Background**

I have an ImageView which is used to display previews of a file.

I would like to have the ImageView with a checkerboard background, so that when a file with transparency is rendered on top (such as PNG and SVG files) the checkerboard shows through on the transparent parts.

I have found lots of questions on StackOverflow on how to create the checkered background and this question is not entirely specific to that.

I am currently doing it in code.  I create a 2 by 2 bitmap (top left/bottom right are one colour, top right, bottom left are the other colour) where the size of each box is specified. Then i create the main bitmap by drawing this small bitmap repeatedly.

```
int checkeredBackgroundSquareSize= 16;

private static Bitmap getCheckeredBitmap(int size) {
    size = (size > 0) ? size : DEFAULT_SQUARE_SIZE;
    int colorOne = ContentApplication.appCtx().getColor(R.color.checkerboard_background_color_one);
    int colorTwo = ContentApplication.appCtx().getColor(R.color.checkerboard_background_color_two);

    // width/height is twice the size of the individual squares
    Bitmap squareBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size*2, size*2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Paint bitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    bitmapPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(squareBitmap);

    // draw 2 rectangles on 2 rows
    // top left and bottom right are the first colour
    // top right and bottom left are the second colour

    // set colour for top left/bottom right squares
    bitmapPaint.setColor(colorOne);
    // Square 1 : top left
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, size, size);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, bitmapPaint);
    // Square 2 : bottom right
    rect.offset(size, size);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, bitmapPaint);

    // change colour for top right/bottom left squares
    bitmapPaint.setColor(colorTwo);
    // Square 3 : top right
    rect.offset(-size, 0);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, bitmapPaint);
    // Square 4: bottom left
    rect.offset(size, -size);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, bitmapPaint);

    return squareBitmap;
}
```

I then create a Bitmap the size of my preview image, and use the checkered background bitmap to repeatedly draw on the canvas before the preview image is added on top.

```
// Create a Bitmap to render our SVG to
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

// Create a Canvas to use for rendering
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

// If we don't specify a viewport box, then AndroidSVG will use the bounds of the Canvas
// as the viewport.  So a scale of 1.0 corresponds to that size
canvas.scale(scaling,scaling );

// create the checkered background, indicating transparency
Bitmap square = getCheckeredBitmap(checkeredBackgroundSquareSize);
BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(square, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setShader(shader);

// in your draw method
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, paint);
```

**The issue**

My previews can be different sizes, for example 100x100, 6000x2000 etc  As i am creating the initial bitmap on these sizes, the final image for the files all render looking like the squares on the checkered background are different sizes.

I need to have the checkerboard look exactly the same regardless of the overlaid image's size.

Is there a way to set a background image for an ImageView to be an image. I can only see how to set it to a drawable and I can not see how to define a checkboard as an xml drawable.

Comment: Probably going to be much simpler to just subclass `Drawable` and draw the checkered grid with `Canvas` rectangles.

Comment: Here's a very quick example, just to show how it might be simpler: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E9OFBg_9zDSYVtb03oTvkEoDt4hYzHB9/view?usp=share_link. Looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY55E.png.

Comment: This is perfect and just what i wanted.  

Could you please add this information as an answer to this question so i can give you the credit for the answer.

Comment: Ah, good to hear! I'm not posting new answers here atm, though, so please feel free to finish up this question however you like. Thanks for the offer. I really appreciate it. Glad I could help. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Mike M gave the answer that solved my issue.  See Mike's comments to the first post

Create your own Drawable that renders the checkerboard

```
public class CheckerboardDrawable extends Drawable {

    // I inadvertently ran the example image with Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG, but
    // we actually don't want that 'cause we're looking for crisp, clean lines.
    private final Paint paint = new Paint();
    private int checkeredBackgroundSquareSize = 16;
    private int colorOne = Color.LTGRAY;
    private int colorTwo = Color.WHITE;

    @Override
    public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        final Rect bounds = getBounds();
        final int squareSize = checkeredBackgroundSquareSize;
        final int columns = bounds.width() / squareSize + 1;
        final int rows = bounds.height() / squareSize + 1;

        canvas.translate(bounds.left, bounds.top);
        for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
            for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
                paint.setColor((c + r) % 2 == 0 ? colorOne : colorTwo);
                final int x = c * squareSize;
                final int y = r * squareSize;
                canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + squareSize, y + squareSize, paint);
            }
        }
        canvas.translate(-bounds.left, -bounds.top);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {}

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(@Nullable ColorFilter colorFilter) {}
}
```

Then add the drawable to the ImageView

```
final ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
imageView.setBackground(new CheckerboardDrawable());
```